# Need to reset the file permission in plesk

Tags: php, file-permissions, control-panel

I use the plesk panel to upload and download the files from the server , currently the **httpdocs** folder permission is being set to   **rwx r-x ---** and when i try to access the folder then it does not allows me to access the folder from the FTP as well as from the plesk.

From the plesk though i get an error following error:

Unable to change directory to /httpdocs: filemng: opendir failed: Permission denied
 System error 13: Permission denied

i need to change the folder permission for the httpdocs so that i can access the files in it.

i have tried to refer the KB parallel http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/1528

but was confused in the sense that how could i change the permission. i am using windows PC , please guide me on this , thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, after i tried to install Magento from the Plesk application manager. I searched and got this link http://kb.odin.com/en/124519and did it exactly as the article instructed. domain.tld - it means the particular domain name with its extension, such as .com, .org, .net. Everything worked, in ftp and file manager i was able to access the files and folders.

**Resolution**

Run the commands below with superuser privileges to download the archived shell script.

Unzip it and execute, providing the needed domain name as an argument:

~# wget http://kb.sp.parallels.com/Attachments/23464/Attachments/recover_plesk_directories.zip

~# unzip recover_plesk_directories.zip

~# sh recover_plesk_directories.sh domain.tld

domain.tld = yourdomainname.com/org/net... whatever, i hope i had been more clear....

For each domain you shall run the command 'sh recover_plesk_directories.sh domain.tld' separately.

Comment: Please edit your post to explain more of how the solution actually works, or even quote directly from that page, as it stands your answer seems to be lacking a little information to clearly resolve the problem on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Login on server as root via ssh connection and restore default permissions for virtual host directories with help of following command:

/usr/local/psa/bin/repair --restore-vhosts-permissions